# Change the Spring Cloud Config server uri after startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I bootstrap my springboot app to point to a default config server to fetch the config props at startup, the config server changes the `spring.cloud.config.uri` (don't ask me why :D) to point to a different config server... when I invoke the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint I want to be able to switch the config server uri out to the new one that I just received.

I looked at the [spring-cloud-config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config) source but the beans there don't seem to be annotated with `@RefreshScope`.

The springboot env `/actuator/env` seems to be showing the new uri received but the config client beans still seem to be pointing to the bootstrap uri.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I am fairly new to using springboot.

Thanks!

Comment: Using Service Discovery to lookup config server is probably the closest I can think of http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#discovery-first-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I cannot use Service Discovery for the time being, I am looking for something without service discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do the same, I removed spring cloud config from initial startup and added it as needed by doing `setConfigUri` followed by `refreshObjects` and that seems to fetch the config from the config server. (Don't forget to add the spring-cloud-config and dependencies to pom.xml)

Here is what I did and it seems to serve the purpose so far. Please feel free to chime in if something seems wrong.

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Autowired
private ContextRefresher refresher;

public void setConfigUri(String uri) throws Exception {
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = env.getPropertySources();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("spring.cloud.config.uri", uri);
    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("defaultProperties", map));
    applicationContext.setEnvironment(env);
}

public void refreshObjects() throws Exception {
    refresher.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting to yourself, autowire a `ContextRefresher` object and call `refresh()`.

Comment: Thank you, was not aware if it. I added it in and seems to work as expected! - KK

Comment: You can change the spring environment by posting to `/env`

Comment: oh wow, never thought about that! probably a better way to do this. Thanks!